# Terraform lookup not working

Tags: terraform

I am trying to lookup map variable but it gives an error. Here are few snippets of my code.

variables.tf

```
variable "count" {
  default = 2
}
variable "providers" {
    default = {
        "0" = "aws"
        "1" = "aws.west"
    }
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "default" {
  count    = "${var.count}"
  provider = "${lookup(var.providers, count.index)}"
  ....
  ....
}
```

Output of `terraform apply`

```
Error configuring: .. error(s) occurred: 
....   
* aws_key_pair.default: provider ${lookup(var.providers, count.index)} couldn't be found
....
....
```

How can we resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with syntax here, Looks like provider is not a valid parameter for aws_key_pair resource, only valid pamams are (key_name and public_key). https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/key_pair.html

Comment: `provider` is a meta-parameter for all resources. It specifies which provider should be used to create the resource. See https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#provider